# Angularjs: not working href when add scope to my directive

Tags: href, angularjs-directive

Here is my html:

```
 <a href="#modal{{screencast.id}}"  role="button" class=" btn" data-toggle="modal"
           ng-click="fetch_comments(screencast.id)" ng-video  url="match_url(screencast.video_url)">Play</a>
```

My directive:

```
'use strict';

App.directive('ngVideo', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { url: '='},

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('click', function () {
            console.log(scope.url);
        });
    }
    }
}]);
```

When I refresh page in `href="#modal{{screencast.id}}"` i have only `href="#modal"`. When I remove `scope: { url: '='}` from directive it works fine, and `href` has value of `screencast.id`.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume the HTML snippet you posted is placed inside an ng-video element in that case (it is not clear from your message but what you describes seems to indicate this).

When you add `scope: { url: '='}` to your directive, you create an isolate scope, which means a new scope is created and all the elements inside this directive will live inside this new scope, disconnected from the parent scope. In that case, your `{{screencast.id}}` binding won't be able to access the screencast object if it was located in the parent scope.

I think for your situation, the best solution would be to remove `scope: { url: '='}` since you are only using it to read a single attribute and use the `attrs` parameter instead.

Your link function could look like:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    var urlAttr;
    //watch url attribute (we have to wait for the binding to be evaluated, hence the $observe)
    attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value) {
        urlAttr = value;
    });
    elem.bind('click', function () {
        if(urlAttr){
            console.log(urlAttr);
        }
    });
}
```